# What does "which" mean in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What does "which" mean in the following sentences,

> Resolution is determined by the ratio of pixels in proportion to image
> size.  This is measured in PPI (Pixels Per Inch). A high resolution
> image will usually have more pixels to every square inch in an image.
> This is measured in ***which*** the number of diagonal pixels are
> taken as a proportion of the length of the diagonal line that goes
> through an image.
>
> ?

(Source: The Relationship Of Image Quality And Image Resolution by Vincent Tabora )

Does "This is measured in ***which*** the number of diagonal pixels are taken as a proportion of the length of the diagonal line" mean "This is measured in ***the number of diagonal pixels and*** the number of diagonal pixels are taken as a proportion of the length of the diagonal line" ?

Does "which" mean "the number of diagonal piexels and" ?

If so, what grammar is this?

Answer (score 2):

The whole is badly written. The sentence you are questioning makes no sense.
The paragraph could be rewritten:

"Resolution is the number of pixels per inch. *High resolution* images have more pixels per inch."

There's no point to mentioning square inches or diagonals.